# How can I clear out duplicate entries in an archived records table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

**Some background info:** I am working on updating an application for a company, and we have a gridview with several columns in it, which vary from labels, to textfields, to dropdowns. Each row in the gridview is for a different 'Entry' which resides in my 'Entry' Table. When a user changes one of these columns (updates the value selected in the dropdown, changes text in the textfield, etc) they WERE clicking an 'update button' which then inserted the change that was made into our 'EntryLog' table. This is how we archive all the changes made to a particular entry. The issue is, the old implementation of the update process would create an archive record for ALL of the entries in the gridview for that page, even when the user only actually updated ONE entry. This means that when a user updated one entry, our 'EntryLog' table was getting flooded with additional archive records that in reality were identical to the previous one (meaning nothing was actually changed for that entry)

**Onto the question:** I have already solved the issue by implementing functionality that only creates an archived record for the single row in the gridview that was modified, but now I am left with the task of cleaning out our 'EntryLog' table of all of those falsely archived records. If I had to phrase what I am trying to do in English I would say: I want to delete all of the Logs (by LogID [unique ID for each archive entry] ) where each column value is the same as the previous Log column values and have the same 'EntryID' (unique ID for each ENTRY itself, meaning there are many instances of each EntryID in the 'EntryLog' table. )

I am unsure how to even begin to safely phrase this in T-SQL and any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any code to show?  This will help us help you

Comment: @MickyDuncan I do not need any help with my c# code as I have the functionality of the update button itself on my gridview updated to do the right thing, the issue that I am trying to fix now is simply cleaning up all of the mis-archived records in my EntryLog table, so I really don't have any relevant code to show as I am not yet sure how to attempt (in T-SQL) what I tried to phrase in English in my question. If there is any other way that I can be more clear about what I am trying to do please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CHECKSUM()` function to see if the data is identical, without checking every single column.

Assume you have something like this:

```
create table #t (log_id int, c varchar(10), d int, log_date date)

insert #t values
(1, 'aaaaa', 1, '20140101'),
(1, 'aaaaa', 1, '20140102'),
(1, 'aaaaa', 1, '20140103'),
(1, 'bbbbb', 1, '20140104'),
(2, 'ccc', 10, '20140103'),
(2, 'cdd', 10, '20140105')
```

The data in the second and the third row are duplicates. To clean the data, execute this statement:

```
with x as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by log_id, checksum(log_id, c, d) order by log_date) as rn
from #t
)
delete x where rn > 1
```

Comment: Thanks dean! Since nothing is ever as simple as it seems, I now realize that two of the fields in my table are unique IDs, which are the Primary keys of two other tables which are both essentially just comments. So now  I have to figure out how to check if the comments are the same from the last archive if all the other fields are identical, even though it is only related by that ID, and try to keep legit comment changes intact if they are valid in the other tables. Definitely a bit stressful for me but your query is going to help tons, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since all you want to do is delete duplicate records, if I don't mis understand, and from what I read they are all unique by ID you could use a [delete query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) to delete by the row ID something like this:

```
DELETE FROM <TableName>
WHERE <ID>= <value>;
```

Since you did specify that it created quite a few duplicates at once you might want to take a look into parameters using a specified [range](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) to delete them a bit quicker. That would look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM <TableName>
WHERE <ID> BETWEEN <value1> AND <value2>;
```

Comment: The only way that I want to delete a row in this 'EntryLog' Table is if ALL of the columns (other than EntryLogID because those are each unique) are identical to the previous EntryLogID record  that has the same EntryID. The problem is that there are many cases where the EntryID is the same as the previous Log Entry, but it could be a 'valid archive' because one of the other (several) columns has a different value, meaning someone actually changed that specific record and I want to preserve that archive information. I hope that makes sense, I am finding it difficult to clearly describe this.

Comment: I don't quite know how many columns there are for each record and how many records there roughly are to check. But you could delete them using the EntryLogID for the rows that you know that should be deleted. Unfortunately that would become quite a hassle to deal with if there are a lot of rows and/or the rows have a lot of columns. But I don't know that mutch about sql that I would know to have it check the rows in the query, so this is about all I can help with.

Comment: @LeoStotch after seeing the awnser of dean i thought I'd try it out (since it could be usefull to me in the future as well) and it does work + you can specify the column's that you want it to check on for duplicates. you only have to change the #t to your table name and the log_id (2X),c and d to the column names you have. of course you could add a lot more column's. So that's most likely the query you are looking for.

Comment: Yes that looks like it could possibly be what I am looking for! I am going to do a few tests before I accept that as my solution, since I have over 300,000 rows of data I want to be absolutely sure I don't mistakenly delete valid archives. Thank you!

Comment: @LeoStotch i tried it on a db im using as well wich i only gave few of the columns to validate on so there had to be a couple duplicate's at least and it only removed 21 out of 100+ rows so it doesnt delete all etc. i think you should be fine as long as you specify all of the columns. but it never hurts to make a backup for safety