# This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

**This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.**

I have a method where I'm trying to delete all duplicate rows (using the date) and I'm getting the above exception with my code. I understand what the exception means but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in my code to cause it. I have looked over it several times with no luck.

```
            using (OldStockRatingsTableAdapter ratingsAdapter = new OldStockRatingsTableAdapter())
            using (DataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable ratingsTable = new DataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable())
            {
                ratingsAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                ratingsAdapter.Adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 500;
                ratingsAdapter.FillByMarketSymbol(ratingsTable, market, symbol);

                var masterQuery = from c in ratingsTable
                            where c.Symbol == symbol && c.Market == market
                            select c;
                List<DataSet.OldStockRatingsRow> masterRows = masterQuery.ToList();
                List<DataSet.OldStockRatingsRow> masterDistinctRows = masterQuery.DistinctBy(i => i.Date).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < masterDistinctRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var dateQuery = from c in masterRows
                                    where c.Date == masterDistinctRows.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Date
                                    select c;
                    List<DataSet.OldStockRatingsRow> dateRow = dateQuery.ToList(); // getting the exception here

                    if (dateRow.Count > 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j < dateRow.Count; j++)
                        {
                            ratingsTable.RemoveOldStockRatingsRow(dateRow.ElementAtOrDefault(j));
                            Console.WriteLine("Stock rating deleted for " + symbol + " in the " + market + " market!");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // update everything here
                DataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable tempRatingsTable = new DataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable();
                tempRatingsTable = (DataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable)ratingsTable.GetChanges();

                if (tempRatingsTable != null)
                {
                    ratingsAdapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    ratingsAdapter.Adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    ratingsAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
                    ratingsAdapter.Update(tempRatingsTable);
                    tempRatingsTable.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine("Stock rating calculations finished for " + symbol + " in the " + market + " market!");
                }
 }
```

Comment: Side note: You can simplify this `ratingsTable.RemoveOldStockRatingsRow(dateRow.ElementAtOrDefault(j));` and write `ratingsTable.RemoveOldStockRatingsRow(dateRow[j]);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your code but if all that you are trying to do is delete duplicates then maby this code is of some use to you:

```
delete duplicate query
with x as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by <COLUMN>, checksum(<Columns to validate>) order by <COLUMN>) as rn
from <TABLE>
)
delete x where rn > 1
//it will validate multiple columns if more are given
```

Note: this code was not made by me, I'll link the origional post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212283/how-can-i-clear-out-duplicate-entries-in-an-archived-records-table/29212477#29212477). The code was posted by `@dean`.